# non-english chars in google charts label?

Tags: charts, label, non-english

Does non-english characters work in google charts [labels/legends](http://code.google.com/intl/sv/apis/chart/labels.html#chart_legend) ?

This works, the legends shows up fine:

```
var chart_url = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?' + 'cht=bvs' + ...some other stuff... + '&chdl=Lowest price|Average price';
```

This doesn't work, the legends don't show at all:

```
var chart_url = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?' + 'cht=bvs' + ...some other stuff... + '&chdl=L' + unescape("%E4") + 'gsta pris|Genomsnittligt pris';
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

/toby

*-----------edit-----------*

Neither of these works:

'&chdl=Lägsta pris|Genomsnittligt pris'

'&chdl=L& auml;gsta pris|Genomsnittligt pris' (without the space after &)

'&chdl=L%E4gsta pris|Genomsnittligt pris'

%E4 == ä urlencoded.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that most letters will work, but you have to do the equivalent of urlencoding them ([see urlencode()](http://php.net/urlencode)).

Comment: Thanks... but...

Since %E4 is urlencoded, I thought '&chdl=L' + unescape("%E4") + 'gsta pris' would do the trick?

Comment: Because you are sending it over a URL, Google wants it to be urlencoded. Have you tried just sending the URL encoded value?

Answer (score 0):

Struggled with the same problem and it turned out that google charts want the texts urlencoded in UTF-8 (of course...)

So "Lägsta pris" should be == L%C3%A4gsta+pris