# Modify axis labels using Google chart

Tags: google-visualization

I want to add a star label to the chart's x-axis as shown in the image below. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [non-english chars in google charts label?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227837/non-english-chars-in-google-charts-label)

Comment: @Laurel - that question relates to [Google _Image_ Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/) which are now deprecated -- most likely this question is related to the [newer library](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/) -- but hard to say for sure -- mossad, can you share a little code?

Comment: I just want to append "star" on x-axis as shown in image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved  this through passing Unicode(unicode for "star") with my data to google chart API.And it's working.

Thanks you all for support.